How is work OPCODE "JUMPDEST"
does anyone explain how JUMPDEST work in practice??
As I step through the evm instruction, JUMPDEST appears to be fairly equivalent to JUMP or JUMPI.
However, this opcode does not cause any changes to the ESTACK or the MEMORY, so why is it needed? it is same to x86 of '\x90'??

JUMPDEST does nothing. Its purpose is to mark places where the execution could jump to.
It is for security reasons. An exploit won't be able to jump to arbitrary positions in the bytecode.
